# Shell script from Applescript

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line, bash

This has been driving me crazy. I have a script which is an executable within `/usr/local/bin/`, which works perfectly in Terminal, but I am unable to get Applescript to call it:

```
RunShell("estc R505")

on RunShell(oscript)
    do shell script oscript
end RunShell
```

doesn't do a thing. I have tried giving the actual location `/usr/local/bin/estc`instead, and calling it in bash with bash or sh... nothing works. It should return a text string, and works perfectly in terminal.

Comment: What is `estc`, is it a binary executable or a script executable? If the latter and it's calling executables not in the _default_ `PATH` passed to the `do shell script` _command_, then the second portion of my answer should help. BTW What does the `estc` _command_ do?

Answer (score 2):

In **Script Editor**, if you *run* the following **AppleScript** *command*:

```
do shell script "echo $PATH"
```

You'll see how the `PATH` is defined to the `do shell script` *command*:

```
"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

You need to include the **fully qualified pathname** to any **executable** that's not in the `PATH`, shown above, in order for it to work in an **AppleScript** `do shell script` *command*.

---

Another *option* is to add an `export PATH` *command* to the `do shell script` *command*, e.g.:

```
set exportPath to "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:"
```

And in your case, use it as, e.g.:

```
RunShell("estc R505")

on RunShell(oscript)
    set exportPath to "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:; "
    do shell script exportPath & oscript
end RunShell
```

Obviously adjust the `...` portion of `export PATH=$PATH:...` to reflect your actual `PATH` that's not included in the *default* `PATH` passed to the `do shell script` *command* as shown further above.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
do shell script "PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH estc R505"
```